# google earth unfilled polygon

Tags: kml, google-earth

I know this isn't exactly a programming question, but there may be some libraries/algorithms to do this, so I thought I could get a good answer. I have a polygon in google earth kml that I Want to make unfilled. I can do that by nesting 2 polygons, the inner being slightly smaller than the outer. Is there a way to dynamically determine the coordinates of the inner polygon given the outer polygon? I didn't know if there was a standard, well known way to do this. Or is there a way in kml/google earth to mark a polygon as unfilled?

thanks,
Jeff

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Under PolyStyle, can you use fill=0 ?  From [Google's interactive sampler](http://code.google.com/apis/kml/documentation/kmlreference.html#polystyle):

```
<PolyStyle id="ID">
  <!-- inherited from ColorStyle -->
  <color>ffffffff</color>            <!-- kml:color -->
  <colorMode>normal</colorMode>      <!-- kml:colorModeEnum: normal or random -->

  <!-- specific to PolyStyle -->
  <fill>1</fill>                     <!-- boolean -->
  <outline>1</outline>               <!-- boolean -->
</PolyStyle>
```

Comment: @Jeff: no prob.  Glad it worked.  I have not used the fill arg, but I figured it should be the right one.